# Турбо паскаль: первое число в массиве меньше остальных?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать программу для турбо паскаля с помощью массива. Имеется одномерный массив целых случайных чисел, состоящий из `N=20` элементов. Программа должна давать ответ на вопрос: «Правда ли что первое число меньше остальных?

```
Program L15;
  var a,b,c,d:integer;
begin
  writeln('Введите 4 числа');
  readln(a,b,c,d);
  if ( (a<b) and (a<c) and (a<d) ) 
    then
      writeln('Да')
    else
      writeln('Нет');
end.
```

остальные через for, while, repeat.

Comment: вы все 20 элементов собираетесь писать через a,b,c,d...?
что бы вам подсказали, нужно хотя бы базовые понятия иметь.
Массив это отдельный тип данных, а не перечисление переменных через запятую.
Не люблю посылать туда но, http://bit.ly/Vfm5sc

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант решения:

```
Program L15;
var 
m:array [1..20] of integer;
i:integer;
f:Boolean;
begin
f:=true;
for i:=1 to 20 do
begin
writeln('Введите числo #'+IntToStr(i));
readln(m[i]);
  end;
for i:=2 to 20 do
begin    if m[1]>m[i] then f:=False;
  end;   
  if f then
      writeln('Да первое число меньше остальных')
    else
      writeln('Нет, первое число не меньше остальных');
end.
```

Comment: не плохо было бы ещё random прикрутить, вместо ручного ввода

Comment: Ну если нежно заполнить случайными числами, то
достаточно строки

writeln('Введите числo #'+IntToStr(i));

readln(m[i]);


Заменить на

Randomize;
m[i]:=Random(100);